# Ajax request but no content

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, request

I'm trying to create an Ajax request and then parse the response header to get the "Location" attribute. This is my code :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 301) {
        alert('test');
        var header = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
        console.log(header);
    }
}
request.open('GET', hrefAttr, true);
request.send(null);
```

The problem is that for some reason, the request is send and the response is received too (red "GET" request+response in Firebug), but I don't get any "test" alert nor any text in the firebug console.

EDIT: This is the modified code :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
console.log(request.readyState);
    if(request.readyState <= 3 && request.status == 301) {
        alert('test');
        var header = request.getResponseHeader('Location');
        console.log(header);
    }
    else if (request.readyState == 0 && request.status == 301) {
        alert('state0');
    }
}
request.open('GET', hrefAttr, true);
request.send();
```

console.log(request.readyState) gives this sequence of states : 1, 1, 2, 4.

In the Firebug console tab the Http Request+Response show fine but in red (if that means anything).

Not sure why I it isn't working...
Edit : I'm using Firefox.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you sure the response code is 301?

Comment: Yes, in the header I get : "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved".

Comment: How about the readyState, is it 0 by chance?

Comment: Ok, so I changed the readyState test from "request.readyState == 4" to "request.readyState <= 3" and also added an else if statement that looks for "request.readyState == 0 && request.status == 301" that triggers an alert, but nothing changes...

Comment: I also added a "console.log(request.readyState)" after function (). When I run the script it goes trough this sequence of states : 1, 1, 2, 4. So, it doesn't record the 0 (normal I think) state and the 3 state but records 2 times the 0 state.

Comment: Just for s&g's add `console.log(request.status)`.  The only thing that it could be is one of those two conditions are not matching.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the XHR will follow the 301 and return the content of the redirected page. You can see the behavior documented at the W3C [here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#infrastructure-for-the-send-method)

> If the XMLHttpRequest origin and the origin of request URL are same origin transparently follow the redirect while observing the same-origin request event rules.

So basically, your request is following the 301 transparently. The browser is automatically redirected and you are unable to do what you intend to do. If you have control over the web server, this can be changed (albeit, against most advice).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what is actually strange. When I send the request, I don't get redirected, I get a Response with the good "301" status and the header in Firebug even shows me the "Location : XYZ" information. Edit: I checked and there isn't any HTML in the Http header.